# move from local xampp server to online server

Tags: android, deployment, webserver

I wrote an android app and for development, I used a local XAMPP server. On the server side I use a mysql db and a few php files that contain the queries. On the android side, I use HttpURLConnection as shown below

```
url = new URL(AppHelper.SERVER_URL + phpFile);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
request.write(parameters);
request.flush();
request.close();
String line = "";
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Now I am at a stage where I would like some friends try out the app, so I want to set up a hosted webserver. Now I am hoping to get suggestions which service to use so that I can salvage and recycle most of my code and files. Please note that I am very unfamiliar with this, so user-friendliness is an important criteria. What are the preferred ways of moving from a local server to a hosted server solution?

Comment: did your php code run in hosting? try it first maybe postman or restapi... so you know is probkem on server side or in your apps...

Comment: I never used a hosted service, not even for testing. hosted services are terra incognita to me. php code is very basic, though. All i does is building queries based on some php parameters and send back a json file.

Comment: yups... doesnt matter hiw yiur code look like... what I mean is did server return result as your axpecting..

Comment: yes, it all works fine using my local server. Ideally, I am looking for a solution that would also easily allow me to sync anything I do locally to the hosted solution as I sometimes work offline, so would be great if the solution would allow me to work in a local environment and just push any changes to the hosted server after testing locally

Comment: if your local return as expected an get inti problem when is mobe to server/host than probably... the priblem is in your hosting not your apps... if you want to switch its goes to hosting or local... use router to switch where the package throw...

Comment: maybe you can give url that should return "json" as your as expected...
so I can try it

Comment: I do not have any problems with my hosting... my problem is I don't have any hosted solution yet. I am looking for suggestions which hosted solution to use for a most seamless transition from locally hosted to using a web hosted solution using a provider like amazon, firebase, ..

Comment: sorry miss understood...
i have no suggestion for that...

Comment: no worries, thanks for trying to help;)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Before I received some replies here I tried to wrap my head around google app engine sql and endpoints. I am still not clear what that actually really does. My questions been answered below, but for my understanding it would be nice if anyone could comment here and let me know how that fits in and what it does. It seems like Endpoints is a fairly easy api, but I don't understand how the whole google backend works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [heroku](http://heroku.com/) for hosting your serverside app. You Just only have to follow the tutorials from heroku and you will get your serverside webservice running in minutes and get URL for your server side webservice.

[here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/php) is documentation for heroku.

You can also use [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) alternatively.

As for me Heroku works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any web hosting site, sign up there. and upload your all php files on that server. Create MySQL Database and create all necessary tables on Server.

Use Filezilla for syncing PHP files from server to local or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any shared server to host your PHP server side code and then it can be used with the android application (Don't forget to change the URL in you android application after hosting you PHP code in to server),as @WinHtalkAung you can use heroku to host your server code, you can also try this [Fortrabbit](https://www.fortrabbit.com/), [pagodabox](https://pagodabox.io/), [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/)

this links are providing free hosting for trail, check before using, and also check this link you may get a idea [Some more](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-anything-like-Heroku-I-can-use-for-a-PHP-site)

Answer (score 1):

You have several options depending on how big is the scale of your application,for example few PHP pages , no framework ,no need for CLI access and small database i'd go for cheap shared hosting since you are still prototyping it.

But as your application gets bigger and bigger your requirements for hosting will change from shared hosting probably to VPS or Heroku.

Personally I'd go for VPS for more flexibility and remember using Git will make it easier during development for deploying repeatedly after fixing bugs and making changes

[Heart Internet UK](http://heartinternet.uk) have reasonable prices I think and [this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwirmbCYwbDNAhXKXhoKHd3oCzoQFgg0MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcodefol.io%2Fposts%2Fwhen-should-you-not-use-heroku&usg=AFQjCNGwNttweHx79F8isKLqHmHfsM1FZg&sig2=b-9Bbl2dVNmN8ib63yQr7Q&bvm=bv.124817099,d.ZGg) is useful reading comparing Heroku to other options

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Before I received some replies here I tried to wrap my head around google app engine sql and endpoints. I am still not clear what that actually really does. My questions been answered below, but for my understanding it would be nice if anyone could comment here and let me know how that fits in and what it does. It seems like Endpoints is a fairly easy api, but I don't understand how the whole google backend works

Answer (score 1):

Initially host your code in a git repository provided by [github](https://github.com) or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org)(1-5users) for free of cost. Then try to deploy your app using heroku or other deployment tools on hosted sites offered by many service providers reviewed and listed [here](http://web-hosting-review.toptenreviews.com) .

Otherwise go for [rackspace](https://www.rackspace.com), [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com) or [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/) for deploying app on custom environment as like setting up your local environment.

Answer (score 1):

## Simple & Direct

1. Select and signup at any hosting service that supports php and mysql (*almost all of them support these*) top ones being **rackspace** and **digital ocean**
2. Move your files to their server by *FTP*.

Congratulations your application is up and running!!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to test your app with **FEW** friends right??
There is a app called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)
which allows you to forward your localhost:#### port to one of its online held ports and your friends can use the link to indirectly access your local machine.

SO if your friends find some bugs that can be fixed by few simple lines of code you can do that in your local machine and you are ready to go. NO GIT PUSHES ,NO Filezilla messes nothing.. This is a viable test option for you if u are planing to stick with only few friends and check the user acceptance testing NOT for actual deployment.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like an interesting solution, but I can't leave my laptop running and online 24/7 currently. It is very good to know that such a solution exists. thanks

Comment: yeah great for testing purposes only, as i mentioned above in the answer.