# How Put xampp server Online for remote access outside

Tags: apache, xampp

I want to allow remote access for my xampp server .

Actually i am working for web services i want that if we are on same network i can access the web from other system using IP

so for that i need to allow outside access.

`xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf` directory

I tried to make some changes in config file but not working.

Might be need to make some changes here

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
AllowOverride AuthConfig
Require local
```

But not sure what to change

Thanks for Help in advance

Comment: You need to bind to _all_ network interfaces, not just the loopback _and_ you need to open the port the http server listens on in your local firewall.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [move from local xampp server to online server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562076/move-from-local-xampp-server-to-online-server)

Comment: "IMPORTANT: Enabling external access for phpMyAdmin in production environments is a significant security risk. You are strongly advised to only allow access from localhost. A remote attacker could take advantage of any existing vulnerability for executing code or for modifying your data."  
https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html  "How do I enable access to phpMyAdmin from the outside?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your line of code as

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
AllowOverride AuthConfig
Require all granted
```

Its working for me

Refrence:https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html

Question on above reference

> How do I restrict access to phpMyAdmin from the outside?