# XAMPP remote access on windows server

Tags: apache, networking, tcp, xampp, windows-server

I am running a website in `XAMPP` on `localhost` in `Windows Server 2016`. I am trying to make it public so anyone can access it via the IP (and later the domain).

So I checked that the server port 80 (TCP) is open in the firewall settings.
But `portqry.exe` returns:

```
TCP port 80 (http service): FILTERED
portqry.exe -n xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -e 80 -p TCP exits with return code 0x00000002.
```

I did what I found in other similar questions: [stackoverflow xampp to public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550742/how-put-xampp-server-online-for-remote-access-outside)

I restarted apache but I still can't access the website remotely.

Obviously, I am missing something because I have no previous experience or knowledge on this matter. What else can I try?

Comment: Are the people you want using your site on the same connection as you? Like school or company domain

Comment: @TiagoSilva no it should be public on internet. anyone should be able to access it no matter the network

Comment: I´ve seen this article that probably will help you https://managewp.com/blog/how-to-access-a-local-website-from-internet-with-port-forwarding please let me know if it did

Comment: @TiagoSilva port 80 is open and xampp is configured to that port also so I dont think that I am missing the port forwarding

Comment: I see, well there are some tools to help you out on this post i found, https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/